# Как отключить обертывание в div от joomla?

Tags: html5, cms, joomla, joomla3

При попытке добавить html модуль с кодом

```
  <li class="modules_info d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="modules_info-top">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <span class="top_title">Основы 3d моделирования: <br> от нуля до первой анимированной модели на примере blender</span>
                            <span class="top_number">№2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="more_info2"> 
                        Какой-то текст
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modules_info-bottom">
                        <a href="#" class="bottom_lector">Арапова Ольга,</a>
                        <span class="bottom_duration">40 минут</span>
                        <button class="bottom_see_more" onclick="open()">Подробнее</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Joomla автоматически добавляет div и ul, в итоге получается вот так

```
<div class="custom">
    <ul>
<li class="modules_info d-flex flex-column">
<div class="modules_info-top">
<div class="d-flex"><span class="top_title">Основы 3d моделирования: <br> от нуля до первой анимированной модели на примере blender</span> <span class="top_number">№2</span></div>
<div class="more_info2">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
<div class="modules_info-bottom"><a class="bottom_lector" href="#">Арапова Ольга,</a> <span class="bottom_duration">40 минут</span> <button class="bottom_see_more">Подробнее</button></div>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Можно ли как-то убрать этот div и ul, что бы код вставлялся в изначальном виде?